# How to measure Sales lift for a campaign without experimental design?

Tags: predictive-models, experiment-design, treatment-effect, control-group, apriori

I want to be able to calculate Sales Lift for a campaign conducted but prior to campaign no control group was established. So, I cannot measure the impact on Sales because of campaign to treatment group with control group because of no prior experiment design.
Is there any alternate way to measure Sales Lift?

I would appreciate any leads on approach to this problem including methodology/algorithm to use in this situation.

Comment: I think the best bet is to compare against last month and remove any effects of seasonality.  Is this the most robust approach?  No, but I think it should work well for your needs.